# new account command not recognizing email as string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a new account, but every time I run the command I get the following error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 15 unexpected
> '@blahblah.com'. syntax error line 4 at position 15 unexpected
> '@blahblah.com'.

It seems like the command isn't seeing the email address as a string.

I've already tried wrapping the email address in quotes, but then I get an error that I don't have permission to create a new account.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is really that you don't have permissions to create a new account, as email address should be wrapped in single quotes.  Are you an `ORGADMIN` on an account that has been enabled with the Organizations functionality?  Can you share your statement?  Are you trying to create a new Snowflake account or are you referring to USERS as accounts (common mistake in terminology).

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I have SYSADMIN. Is That enough mojo? If not, how on earth do I get ORGADMIN? I am trying to create a new Snowflake account with a different region than my first account.

create account account2
  admin_name = myloginname
  admin_password = 'mypassword'
  email = julia@blahlah.com
  edition = standard
  region = aws_eu_west_2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the link here to help:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations.html

First, your account has to be enabled with an Organization functionality.  This isn't done by default, so you have to contact support.

Second, this will enable the ORGADMIN role in your account, which ACCOUNTADMIN can leverage or grant to other roles.

Once you have these setup and your active role is ORGADMIN, then you can run the `CREATE ACCOUNT` statement that you are trying to run.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!